# Is there a way to have a bootstrap progress bar animate when increasing in value, but not when resetting to 0?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

If I have a bootstrap progress bar that cycles from 0% to 100%, and back to 0% relatively quickly, by the time the "reset to 0%" animation finishes, the new value is already around ~40%, so the resulting effect makes the progress bar look as though it's bouncing between 40% to 100% to 40% to 100%, etc...

Is there any way to have the progress bar animate when increasing its value, but to make a discrete "jump" when decreasing in value?  If not, is there another way that I can achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue using AngularJS's ng-class directive.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0us8L6d8/8/) is the example.

And a snippet of the solution:

```
<div class='progress'>
<div class='progress-bar' ng-class=\"{'no-animations': counter == 0, 'animated': counter != 0}\" role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='50' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' ng-style=\"{width: counter + '%'}\">
<span>Action: {{counter}}%</span>
</div>
</div>
```